# Getting logs of cronjob script execution with logs in the body of the email

Tags: linux, shell, email, cron

I'm trying to get the cron job to send me an email directly after the script execution and get the last logs into the body of the email

```
21 14 * * * /opt/anaconda/bin/python /Path/to/Script/script.py >> /Path/to/logfile/log.txt 2>&1 | mail -s "cronjob OK" "first@mail.x,second@mail.x"
```

How could I do that? what should I add?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not really describing a problem. However, I think it would be easiest to not pipe anything to a file / invoke `mail` manually. Just set `MAILTO=first@mail.x,second@mail.x` before the cronjob-line and Cron should already mail you any output. Given your system is capable of sending emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is not producing any output because you just redirected it to a file.

`cron` will send any output by email to the owner of the cron job anyway. You can specify a different address with `MAILTO` in some `cron` implementations.

```
MAILTO=first@mail.x,second@mail.x
21 14 * * * /opt/anaconda/bin/python /Path/to/Script/script.py 2>&1 | tee -a /Path/to/logfile/log.txt
```

The `tee` command saves a copy of standard input to the file (`-a` says to append instead of overwrite) and to standard output.

If you need more control over the generated message (e.g. to use a different Subject: header if Cron's is not acceptable) maybe keep the `tee` but put back the pipe to `mail`.